# Separate a list of items into new, present and present-and-needs-stuff-done-to-it

Tags: java, arraylist, coding-style, code-cleanup

I have a list of items which I want in my database. Some of the items are new and have to be saved, others are already in the database, but have to be updated and some of those that need an update might be eligible for a special treatment.

Now I just run through them and put them in other lists according to their properties and then hand the lists to the respective database (or special) methods that deal with it.

I just don't think it's pretty, it does a bit much and it has nested ifs.
But can't really come up with a nicer way of doing this.

Here is the (slightly simplified) code

```
List<Item> newItemList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> existingItemList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> specialItemList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Item item : items)
{
  if(item.isNew())
  {
    newItemList.add(item);
  }
  else
  {
    if(item.isSpecial())
    {
      specialItemList.add(item);
    }
    existingItemList.add(item);
  }
}

itemHandler.saveItems(newItemList);
itemHandler.updateItems(existingItemList);
specialManager.specialStuff(specialItemList);
```

Comment: in my personal view: that's how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code does exactly what is required.  Your requirement calls for three different lists, and you iterate items once to create them.  It is the most efficient approach. You could write the code in three lines - see below - (the helper method is for clarity) - but then you iterate items three times (but don't require 3 lists).  I believe any attempt to make 'nicer' code loses some optimization.

```
itemHandler.saveItems(createList(items, i -> i.isNew()));
specialManager.specialStuff(createList(items, i -> !i.isNew() && i.isSpecial()));
itemHandler.updateItems(createList(items, i -> !i.isNew()));
```

Helper method:

```
public List<Item> createList(List<Item> allItems, Predicate<Item> p) {
    return allItems.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I like a lot your answer and the explanation is fine : clarity versus optimization . You have my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you could simplify by grouping the `List`s by State (new or existing).
An enum could represent the state : `enum State {NEW, EXISTING}` and the `Item` class should declare a `State getState()` method.

```
Map<ItemState, List<Item>> itemListByState  = 
                   items.stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getState));

itemHandler.saveItems(itemsByState.get(State.NEW));
itemHandler.updateItems(itemsByState.get(State.EXISTING));
specialManager.specialStuff(itemsByState.get(State.EXISTING).stream()
                                        .filter(Item::isSpecial)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You could of course introduce intermediary variables for the `List`s but I don't think that it is really required and it reduces potential side effects between them.

Comment: hehe a colleague of mine is probably gonna like this answer :D
I don't, but thanks anyways

Comment: Thanks for the feeback. I understand your choice. I also like a lot Ian Mc answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another method like:

```
boolean add(List<Item> items, Item item, boolean doAdd) {
    if (doAdd) {
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
add (newItemList, item, item.isNew());
add (specialItemList, item, item.isSpecial() & !item.isNew());
add (existingItemList, item, !item.isNew());
```